# Есть проект на laravel. База данных MySQL. Как их сопрячь?

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

Есть проект на laravel. База данных MySQL. Как их сопрячь? В какую сторону подумать? Знаю вариант с миграциями, а есть ли ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытались сами разобраться в данном вопросе?
Для сопряжения Laravel и MySQL необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Установить и настроить Laravel, используя инструкции в официальной документации.
2. Создать базу данных MySQL и настроить доступ к ней.
3. Открыть файл .env в корне проекта Laravel и настроить следующие параметры:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=имя_базы_данных
DB_USERNAME=имя_пользователя_базы_данных
DB_PASSWORD=пароль_пользователя_базы_данных
```

4. Создать миграции для создания таблиц в базе данных, используя команду "php artisan make:migration имя_миграции".
5. Написать код для работы с базой данных в соответствии с требованиями проекта.
6. Выполнить миграции с помощью команды "php artisan migrate".

После выполнения этих шагов Laravel будет успешно связан с базой данных MySQL, и вы сможете использовать ее для хранения данных в вашем проекте.

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал выполнять отдельные пункты этой инструкции, но так подробно ещё не находил нигде.

Comment: Разобрался с этим вопросом.